# SQL Server Create table issue - Msg 156

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a table using another table. Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT CASE_ID
  FROM old_table);
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

```
SELECT CASE_ID INTO new_table FROM old_table;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (case_id int);
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT CASE_ID FROM old_table;
```

The former seems a closer match to what you are attempting now, but the latter is useful for more complicated table definitions, to include things like NULL restrictions, constraints, keys, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sql will support creation of table in some ways

```
SELECT CASE_ID
into new_table
  FROM old_table;
```

or create new_table and insert  rows into new table from old table like this

```
create table new_table
(
CASE_ID int
)

insert into new_table(CASE_ID)
SELECT CASE_ID

      FROM old_table
```